# How can i show the recycle view data from listview to next intent activity by id in card view this is my code please check and show the result

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-recyclerview

How can I show the recycle view data from `ListView` to next intent activity by id in card view this is my code please check and show the result

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.tanuj.recycleview.Product;
import com.example.tanuj.recycleview.R;

import java.util.List;


public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    private TextView textViewTitle,textViewShortDesc,textViewRating,textViewPrice;
    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Product> productList;

    public ProductAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Product> productList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list, null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position)  {
        Product product = productList.get(position);


        Glide.with(mCtx)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(product.getImage())
                .into(holder.imageView);

        holder.textViewTitle.setText(product.getTitle());
        holder.textViewShortDesc.setText(product.getShortdesc());
        holder.textViewRating.setText(String.valueOf(product.getRating()));
        holder.textViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(product.getPrice()));


        holder.textViewTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String data = "{}";
                Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx,GalleryActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mCtx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //Set on click on description
        holder.textViewShortDesc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mCtx,"You are click On Description : " +textViewShortDesc,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //Set on click on price
        holder.textViewPrice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mCtx,"You are click On Price",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        holder.textViewRating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mCtx,"You are click on rating",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewTitle, textViewShortDesc, textViewRating, textViewPrice;
        ImageView imageView;

        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            textViewShortDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShortDesc);
            textViewRating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRating);
            textViewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Please make your product class(or model class) implements **Parcelable**. Android Studio will provide you implementation of parcelable.
2. Now you can send any your product object in intent extras like [Example](https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2015/05/android-parcelable-tutorial-list-class-2.html)

Comment: Provide your model class. I will provide u method to pass object in another activity